# A schema in a relational database is based on association or hierarchy

Tags: database, associations, hierarchy, value-objects

If we are to map our db schema to java layer , should it be a hierarchy of domain objects or association between domain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like Hibernate or TopLink or other ORM solutions.

Better yet, just use those.

Comment: Let me find out how hibernate or top link does it !!

Comment: Good idea.  Don't reinvent the wheel, unless your purpose is to learn how to make wheels: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html